# Including Dropzone.css in react

Tags: reactjs, dropzone.js

I want to use dropzone in react. I included dropzone using [opensource module.](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/React-Dropzone-Component)

But I can't able to include css file as given on its documentation.

How I can include required css file?

Comment: If you are rendering the component on a basic html file, linking to the stylesheet from there works as well. If you wanted more granular control, it can depend on how you are loading CSS into your project. Are you using webpack?

Comment: Dropzone's are fairly easy to create. So why not just build it yourself?
I'll link my answer from the other day: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38689897/769083. Here's a codepen of a dropzone: http://codepen.io/jzmmm/pen/bZjzxN?editors=0011

Comment: Yes, Aug I am using react-redux-starter-kit.

Comment: Thanks, Jzm,I want but I have no time to create my own dropzone.