# Applying react Component on html div while keeping the appearance of div as it is

Tags: reactjs

I am a noob and I am trying to use a react component to attach some listeners to an html div section.

Using the component, I just want to attach listeners to the html div to listen to some events while keeping the appearance and formatting of html the same.

**- Is it possible to return html's div from render() of the component?**

something like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
...
...
document.getElementById("div_id").addEventListener("drop", this._onDrop.bind(this));


render() { return document.getElementById("div_id");  }
```

(Above code does not work but I am mentioning it just to give an example of what I am trying to do)

**- Is there any other way to apply just the listeners to the html div?**

.

#### What I have tried so far:

Above code gives following error:

`Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLDivElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

When I return null in render(), it clears the html section.

```
render() {return false;}

or 

render() {return null;}
```

Comment: This was answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689741/how-to-attach-drag-drop-event-listeners-to-a-react-component

Comment: @DCTID: thanks for chiming in but this solution also outputs something in render function, which is not the same as html's div on which component is applied.

Comment: If you don't render anything then your render function should just return null.

As four your event listeners you can use componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount to add and remove them.

Comment: @EugenTimm ah great, I didn't know about componentWillMount/Unmount. But still the problem is if render() returns null, it wipes/clears the div of html on which this component is applied. I want to keep the formatting and the elements inside div section.